# Classification of strongly lcm-closed sets

Tags: nt.number-theory

I call a set X of positive integers *strongly lcm-closed* if a,b ∈ X if and only if lcm(a,b) ∈ X.  In the finite case X is the set of divisors of lcm<sub>x ∈ X</sub>x.  But in the infinite case it is more interesting, for example, $\{a \geq 1: a \not\equiv 0 \pmod p\}$ and $\{p^a:a \geq 0\}$ for any prime p, are strongly lcm-closed sets.

> Which sets are strongly lcm-closed sets?

This question arose in my [Ph.D. thesis](https://sites.google.com/site/rknmodn/papers) (p.107) where strongly lcm-closed sets describe where autotopisms of Latin squares give rise to subsquares.

As a side question:

> Is there a common name for strongly lcm-closed sets?

Comment: Excellent!  This is exactly what I'm after.  By the way, I would accept both answers below, if I could.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a [supernatural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernatural_numbers) $N$, the set of positive integer divisors of $N$ is a strongly lcm-closed set.  And any nonempty strongly lcm-closed set $X$ arises in this way, with $N$ equal to the supernatural lcm of the $x$ in $X$.  (See Serre, *Galois cohomology* for the notion of supernatural number: it is a formal product over primes, $\prod_p p^{n_p}$, where each $n_p$ is in $\lbrace 0,1,2, \dots,\infty \rbrace$.)

Comment: I do not see why every strongly-lcm set could be obtained this way, how about {p^2a} for p fix?

Comment: Your example doesn't satisfy the definition: we have lcm(p,p^2) in X, so p and p^2 should be in X too.

Comment: Oh, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

Those would be the [ideals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(order_theory)) in the lattice of positive integers ordered by divisibility.